I laughed at a name in Arabic which mean an Angel (Beevi)
I laughed at a joke with my friend who made a joke about the name Beevi which meant Angel,Though Im not content with any jokes associated with islam but I couldn't control my laughter and still laughed,Did I commit an act of kufr?
